# H2O GLM in Python Repeats Lambda Values in Regularization

Tags: python, h2o, glm

When fitting a GLM in H2O_cluster_version: 3.32.0.5 with

```
lamdba_search = True, nlambdas = 20, and lambda_min_ratio = .0001
```

My team and I receive 24 lambdas in our regularization path. The last 4 lambdas in the path are repeats of the first 4, the largest values.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tweedie
import scipy

import os
import sys
import time

import h2o
from h2o.estimators.glm import H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator
from h2o.grid.grid_search import H2OGridSearch
sys.path.append(h2odir)
from h2o_auto_init import h2o_auto_init

os.system(h2oshellscript)
    
time.sleep(10)
    
h2o_auto_init()

#sample data
resp = np.random.choice(range(0,100),size=1000)
pred1 = np.random.choice(range(40,50),size=1000)
pred2 = np.random.choice(range(20,30),size=1000)
pred3 = np.random.choice([1,2,3,4,5],size=1000)
weight = np.random.choice([1,1,1,.9,.37],size=1000)
folds = np.random.choice([1,2,3,4,5],size=1000)

data = pd.DataFrame({'resp': resp, 'pred1':pred1,'pred2':pred2,'pred3':pred3,'weight':weight,'fold_column':folds})

predictors = ['pred1','pred2','pred3']

    # convert pandas df to h2oframe
H2Odata = h2o.H2OFrame(data, column_names=data.columns.tolist())


  
    # set up model
model = H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator(
        family="tweedie",
        tweedie_link_power = 0,
        tweedie_variance_power = 1.7,
        lambda_search=True,
        early_stopping = False,
        lambda_min_ratio = 0.0001,
        nlambdas=20,
        alpha=.5,
        standardize = True,
        weights_column='weight',
        solver = 'IRLSM',
        #beta_constraints = constraints,
        keep_cross_validation_models = True,
        keep_cross_validation_predictions = True,
        keep_cross_validation_fold_assignment=True
)
    # Train the model with training and validation data
model.train(
        x=predictors, 
        y='resp',
        training_frame=H2Odata,
        fold_column = 'fold_column'
)


# get full regularization paths
#list of cross validation model objects
regpath_h2o_cv=[]
for i in range(0,len(model.cross_validation_models())):
        regpath_h2o_cv.append(H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator.getGLMRegularizationPath(model.cross_validation_models()[i]))

H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator.getGLMRegularizationPath(model.cross_validation_models()[0])['lambdas']
```

When I run this, there is an extra lambda, a repeat of the first lambda.
Can anyone provide guidance on why H2O is providing more lambdas than requested, and especially repeated lambdas?
Does this mean it is fitting unnecessary models?

Our real use case is on very large data, and any time we can save
avoiding unnecessary modeling will be helpful.

Comment: Might be useful to include the H2O version number and platform, in case it is a bug. A fully reproducible example would allow people to confirm it happens, and is not just something about your data or setup. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example